# How to add duplicate fields in list in JSON deserialize method?

Tags: apex, rest-api, json, deserialize

I need to parse this JSON and store **services** in a list but getting exception in deserialize due to duplicate field. Can someone help what I need to change to make this work?
I have generated the class using Json2Apex app. Please see below the json body:

```
{
    "Subscriptions": [
        {
            "Subscription": {
                "SAPOrder": "SAP123",
                "RequestType": "New",
                "OrderStatus": "0",
                "Services": [
                    {
                        "Service": [
                            {
                                "attribute": {
                                    "name": "Resilience",
                                    "value": "Terminated"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "attribute": {
                                    "name": "Number",
                                    "value": "1234"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "attribute": {
                                    "name": "serviceStartDate",
                                    "value": "2018-08-220T02:13:20"
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "Service": [
                            {
                                "attribute": {
                                    "name": "Resilience",
                                    "value": "Terminated"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "attribute": {
                                    "name": "Number",
                                    "value": "1234"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "attribute": {
                                    "name": "serviceStartDate",
                                    "value": "2018-08-220T02:13:20"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

** JSON2APEX Class-**

```
@RestResource(urlMapping = '/SubsUpdate')
global with sharing Class SubsUpdate   
{

    @HttpPost
    global static void parseJson()
    { 

        RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
        System.debug('--req' + req);
        String jsonRequest = req.requestBody.toString();
        System.debug('incoming json request string' + jsonRequest);


       JSON2Apex res = (JSON2Apex)JSON.deserialize(jsonRequest, JSON2Apex.class);
        System.debug('--call' + res);

    }
public class JSON2Apex 
{
public List<Subscriptions> Subscriptions;}

public class Services {
        public List<Service> Service;
    }

    public class Attribute {
        public String name;
        public String value;
    }

    public class Subscriptions {
        public Subscription Subscription;
    }

    public class Service {
        public Attribute attribute;
    }

    public class Subscription {
        public String SAPOrder;
        public String RequestType;
        public String OrderStatus;
        public List<Services> Services;
    }

}
```

Comment: json2apex isn't going to help you here; you need to write an explicit, custom parser.

Comment: @sfdcfox In some json validators I got error of invalid json. So I am also want to confirm that is this valid json which we can provide external system to hit our service?

Comment: Seems that you've deleted your previous question on the same topic. I'll say it again, the main issue is that your JSON is invalid. Fixing your JSON should probably be where you focus your efforts.

Comment: It's not strictly forbidden, but most parsers cannot handle this scenario. You should consider this as invalid JSON. Instead, each Service should be wrapped in its own JSON object, at minimum.

Comment: @DerekF amusingly, I double-checked, and technically the standard allows duplicate keys like this, but it's not recommended.

Comment: @sfdcfox This should be very common scenario where I have to receive record, its child records from external system and update them. Is there a way to modify this json so that it works with json2apex parser? I want to put them in map<string,List<List<Map<String,String>>> so it may be difficult to write custom code to traverse. Please guide.

Comment: @shuklayogesh As David and I said, you need to fix the JSON so it's not duplicating keys. It should be as simple as wrapping each Service key in its own object.

Comment: @sfdcfox I'm unable to change that. If after services it doesn't accept consecutive {{ after services. Please if you can add formatted json as ans I will accept that. I'm unable to find similar format anywhere and struggling from 2 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing just a few characters in the middle makes this valid JSON. Run this through JSON2Apex and you should be fine.

```
{
    "Subscriptions": [
        {
            "Subscription": {
                "SAPOrder": "SAP123",
                "RequestType": "New",
                "OrderStatus": "0",
                "Services": [
                    {
                        "Service": [
                            {
                                "attribute": {
                                    "name": "Resilience",
                                    "value": "Terminated"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "attribute": {
                                    "name": "Number",
                                    "value": "1234"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "attribute": {
                                    "name": "serviceStartDate",
                                    "value": "2018-08-220T02:13:20"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "Service": [
                            {
                                "attribute": {
                                    "name": "Resilience",
                                    "value": "Terminated"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "attribute": {
                                    "name": "Number",
                                    "value": "1234"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "attribute": {
                                    "name": "serviceStartDate",
                                    "value": "2018-08-220T02:13:20"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```